# using inserted and deleted tables in the triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to write triggers to work with the inserted and deleted tables. I have written the trigger for inserting :

```
CREATE TRIGGER FILL_TABLE
ON Person FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @ID int
SELECT @ID = p.ID
FROM Person AS p 
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON p.ID = i.ID 
DECLARE @uName char(30);
SELECT @uName = SYSTEM_USER
INSERT tblOperationLog 
 Values 
 ( @uName, 'user has inserted a row with ID = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @ID) + '', 
    'Insert', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, GETDATE() )
```

I want to write the trigger and use the deleted table just like the inserted one. but I don't know how. I want to retrieve the ID of the deleted rows to fill the second column of the tblOperationLog but I can't. Should I use the inner join in it too?

Comment: i'm using the SQL Server

Answer (score 12):

Your trigger will only work if only one row has been inserted.  As `inserted` is available as a table, you can insert from that table and use all records.  I think you're looking for something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER FILL_TABLE 
ON Person FOR INSERT, DELETE
AS 

  INSERT tblOperationLog  
  SELECT  SYSTEM_USER,'user has inserted a row with ID = ' + ID, 'Insert', 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, getdate()
  FROM inserted

  INSERT tblOperationLog  
  SELECT  SYSTEM_USER,'user has deleted a row with ID = ' + ID, 'Delete', 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, getdate()
  FROM deleted
```

Comment: is there any table for updated rows too? can i use it like the above too?

Comment: @anna - as per @Oded's answer, when an update is performed, the rows are in the deleted table with the old information, and the inserted table with the new information

Answer (score 4):

In SQL server, a trigger has access to two logical tables `INSERTED` and `DELETED` that have the same structure as the table the trigger is defined.

Both tables will be filled on an `UPDATE` trigger. An `INSERT` trigger will only have the `INSERTED` table filled, a `DELETE` trigger will only have the `DELETED` table filled.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx).