# Use trigger how to copy just inserted row

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm using SQL Server 2008, and I have a trigger which I want to copy any rows in the `My_Table` into a archive `History_Table` table.

How to copy the entire old content of the table into the archive each time someone inserts a new row?

My table structure is

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stu_Table]
    (
    [Stu_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Stu_Name] [varchar] (15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Stu_Class] [int] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stu_Table] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Stu_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([Stu_Id]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My archive table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stu_TableHistory]
(
[Stu_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Stu_Name] [varchar] (15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Stu_Class] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stu_TableHistory] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Stu_TableHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([Stu_Id]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My trigger syntax is

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[HistoryKeep]
   ON  [dbo].[Stu_Table]
   INSTEAD OF  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stu_Table WHERE Stu_Id = (SELECT Stu_Id FROM INSERTED)) >= 1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Stu_TableHistory( Stu_Id, Stu_Name, Stu_Class )
        SELECT Stu_Id, Stu_Name, Stu_Class FROM Stu_Table WHERE Stu_Id = (SELECT Stu_Id FROM INSERTED)

        UPDATE x
        SET x.Stu_Name = i.Stu_Name
        FROM dbo.Stu_Table AS x
        INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON i.Stu_Id = x.Stu_Id

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Stu_Table( Stu_Id, Stu_Name, Stu_Class )
        SELECT Stu_Id, Stu_Name, Stu_Class FROM INSERTED
    END
END
```

In a word need help to transfer the old data from student table to archive table. My above trigger syntax can not satisfy me.

If have any query plz ask thanks in advance.

Comment: `INSERTED` is a pseudo-table and can contain *multiple* rows. You need to write queries that accept that reality. Your code is broken in assuming that `SELECT STU_ID from INSERTED` will return 1 result. And it may contain a mixture of rows - some for which the `UPDATE` is appropriate, others for which the plain `INSERT` is.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for reply ,don’t understand your comment description ,will you plz like to share some syntax with elaborate description.Thanks

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336319/using-inserted-and-deleted-tables-in-the-triggers

Comment: See here for documentation on `Inserted` and `Deleted` tables: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of your current trigger, you should have something like:

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[HistoryKeep]
   ON  [dbo].[Stu_Table]
   INSTEAD OF  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @History table (
    Action sysname not null,
    STU_ID [int] NULL,
    [Stu_Name] [varchar] (15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Stu_Class] [int] NULL
)

;MERGE INTO Stu_Table t
USING INSERTED i ON t.STU_ID = i.STU_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET STU_Name = i.STU_Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (STU_ID,STU_NAME,STU_CLASS) VALUES (i.STU_ID,i.STU_NAME,i.STU_CLASS)
OUTPUT $Action,deleted.stu_id,deleted.stu_name,deleted.stu_class INTO @History;

INSERT INTO stu_TableHistory (stu_id,stu_name,stu_class)
select stu_id,stu_name,stu_class from @History where Action='UPDATE'
END
```

Note, also, that you'll need to drop your current PK constraint on `STU_TableHistory`, since as soon as a row is updated more than once, there'll be two entries containing the same `STU_ID`.

---

As per my comment, this treats `INSERTED` as a table containing multiple rows throughout. So if `Stu_Table` contains a row for `STU_ID` 1, the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO STU_Table (STU_ID,STU_Name,STU_Class) VALUES
(1,'abc',null),
(2,'def',null)
```

will *update* the row for `STU_ID` 1, *insert* a row for `STU_ID` 2, and insert *one* row into `stu_tableHistory` (for `STU_ID` 1)