# SQL Server : make update trigger don't activate with no changing value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to track the update changes in a table via a trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TrackTable(...columns same as target table)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dboTrackTable 
ON dbo.TargetTable 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
     INSERT INTO dbo.TrackTable (...columns) 
         SELECT (...columns) 
         FROM Inserted
```

However in real production some of the update queries select rows with vague conditions and update them all regardless of whether they are actually changed, like

```
UPDATE Targettable 
SET customer_type = 'VIP' 
WHERE 1 = 1
--or is_obsolete = 0 or register_date < '20160101' something
```

But due to table size and to analyze, I only want to choose those actually modified data for tracking. How to achieve this goal?

My track table has many columns (so I do not prefer checking inserted and deleted column one by one) but it seldom changes structure.

Comment: https://autoaudit.codeplex.com/

Comment: you can't. Either you check in the `UPDATE trigger` on any column changes or you do that in your `UPDATE query`. An `update trigger` will still fire regardless of any changes to the row or not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following code will be useful.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.TrackTable(...columns same as target table)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dboTrackTable 
ON dbo.TargetTable 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
     INSERT INTO dbo.TrackTable (...columns) 
         SELECT *
         FROM Inserted
         EXCEPT
         SELECT *
         FROM Deleted
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this post is a couple months old now, but for anyone looking for a well-rounded answer:

To exit the trigger if no rows were affected on SQL Server 2016 and up, Microsoft recommends using the built-in `ROWCOUNT_BIG()` function in the [Optimizing DML Triggers section of the Create Trigger documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks-for-dml-triggers).

Usage:

```
IF ROWCOUNT_BIG() = 0
    RETURN;
```

To ensure you are excluding rows that were not changed, you'll need to do a compare of the inserted and deleted tables inside the trigger. Taking your example code:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TrackTable (...columns) 
     SELECT (...columns) 
     FROM Inserted i
         INNER JOIN deleted d
             ON d.[SomePrimaryKeyCol]=i.[SomePrimaryKeyCol] AND
                 i.customer_type<>d.customer_type
```

Microsoft documentation and w3schools are great resources for learning how to leverage various types of queries and trigger best practices.

Answer (score -1):

Prevent trigger from doing anything if no rows changed.

[Writing-triggers-the-right-way](http://aboutsqlserver.com/2014/01/28/writing-triggers-in-the-right-way/)

```
CREATE TRIGGER the_trigger on dbo.Data 
after update
as 
begin
    if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        return
    set nocount on

    /* Some Code Here */
end
```

Get a list of rows that changed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER the_trigger on dbo.data
AFTER UPDATE
AS
SELECT * from inserted
```

[Previous stack overflow on triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336319/using-inserted-and-deleted-tables-in-the-triggers)

@anna - as per @Oded's answer, when an update is performed, the rows are in the deleted table with the old information, and the inserted table with the new information –

Comment: I think it does not work: like my table has 10000 rows with 9900 already VIP, then `UPDATE table SET type = 'VIP' WHERE 1=1` yields `@@ROWCOUNT=10000` and the `inserted` will list out the whole table.

Comment: Hmmm.  What about:. If you have a PK you could join inserted and deleted on PK and then where inserted.col1 <> deleted.col1.  Do you think that would work?